# Why does the compiler generate this code?

Tags: c, visual-c++, assembly, disassembly

I disassembled an object file (most likely generated using the Visual C++ compiler) using `DumpBin` and saw the following piece of code:

```
...         ...
mov         dword ptr [ebp-4],eax       // Why save EAX?
push        dword ptr [ebp+14h]
push        dword ptr [ebp+10h]
push        dword ptr [ebp+0Ch]
push        dword ptr [ebp+8]
mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-4]       // Why restore EAX? Did it change at all?
call        <function>
...         ...
```

Could someone please explain why the EAX register is being saved and restored across these 4 `push` instructions?

Comment: I've seen compilers do dumber things than this...

Comment: @Mysticial: Oh lol... it's the first time I've noticed something like this. :) Good to know.

Comment: Perhaps there is a branch into the first push.

Comment: @RaymondChen: That's a *brilliant* observation... but when I look at the rest of the function, I don't see any jumps of any sort. Unless it's from elsewhere in the module, I don't think that's the cause.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but why would it save EAX because there is a jump to the `push` after it?

Comment: If there is a jump to the push, then the eax register may not match the value on the stack.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Also, maybe it's compiled in release mode, but that variable has been marked as `volatile`, which tells the compiler that such variable may change without it knowing, so it is forced to continuously write/restore it on/from the stack

Comment: I'm not sure that `volatile` would make a difference here. `volatile` pertains to a memory location, but EAX is a register; you can't mark a register as being volatile. So `volatile` would explain [ebp-4] being reloaded *onto* eax immediately before every operation, but not eax being saved.

Comment: For certain arithmetics the compiler _has_ to load a memory location marked volatile into a register, because the operation is not possible as read-modify-write instruction. After this code segment a store might follow, and before this a load may preceed, so from the information at hand it may absoluteley be possible. But posly it't only a missed optimization by VC.

Comment: @drhirsch Ah, because volatile also means that *stores* have to be committed immediately, not just that *reads* deferred to the last moment. I'd not considered that. It would be a bit peculiar for a `volatile` pointer to aim at a stack address (`ebp` offset) but I suppose it's possible.

Comment: @Crashworks: I may be wrong, but `ebp-4` seems to be a function parameter (a pointer or a reference), so it feels even more strange.

Answer (score 6):

Was this built in debug mode? If so, the compiler stores every local variable on the stack so that the debugger can find them in a consistent way.

The elision of such unnecessary stores and reloads is one of the optimizations that constitutes "release" mode.

Comment: I believe it's *supposed* to be release-mode code (there is no 'debug' version of anything related I can see anywhere...), but I'm not sure... I don't have the source code either. But +1 that's a reasonable guess, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`volatile` or not, the only *technical* reason why `EAX` would *have to be initialized* directly before making a function call on Windows were if that `function` is declared `__syscall`, i.e. using the Windows CS_SYSCALL calling convention. Conceptually, this is a bit similar to the UN*X x86_64 convention where `%al` contains the number of floating point type args passed in `%xmm` registers.

The syscall calling convention on Windows is identical to `__cdecl`, i.e. function args on stack in reverse order, but with the addition that `AL` contains a count of the number of arguments; this is done so that the kernel code which is usually at the final end of this knows how much data to read from the user stack onto the kernel stack to retrieve the args.

`EAX` is a scratch register for all calling conventions on 32bit Windows, its value is never preserved over function calls, initializing it directly before making a call is redundant. Even if the variable it holds were `volatile` - because a simple re-load isn't a memory barrier and doesn't "commit" a previous store. In addition, the location `[EBP - 4]` is within the *stack*, so the variable is *local* (and a `volatile` qualifier makes little sense).

If it's not a missed optimization then it could be an invocation of a `__syscall function(...)` with different numbers of arguments, like, hypothetically,

```
__syscall printf_syscall_conv(char *fmt, ...);

void possibly_print_three_vals(char *fmt, int val1, int val2, int val3)
{
    if (*strchr('%', fmt) == '\0')    // if no "%" in fmt, pass no args
        printf_syscall_conv(fmt);
    else
        printf_syscall_conv(fmt, val1, val2, val3);
}
```

This could conceivably create assembly output like yours.